# why my program execute scan and print twice?

Tags: c, linux, exec

I write this program which must execute mkdir and rmdir, the parent must send argument to child and child execute it.

```
void main()
{
  int r; 
  int i;
  int fd[2];
  pipe(fd);
  char arg[100];
  printf("Please Choose one of the following commands: \n");
  printf("1 MKDIR \n");
  printf("2 RMDIR \n");

  while(1)
  {
    printf("You choose: \n");
    scanf("%d ", &r);

    pid_t pid;
    pid = fork();

    printf("Please enter arguments: ");
    scanf("%s ", arg);
    write(fd[1],arg,sizeof(arg));

    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
      if(pid==0)
      {
        switch(r)
        {
          case 1: 
          read(fd[0],arg,sizeof(arg));
          execl("/bin/mkdir", "MKDIR", arg, NULL);

          case 2: 
          read(fd[0],arg,sizeof(arg));
          execl("/bin/rmdir", "RMDIR", arg, NULL);
        }
      }
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that when I execute it it, I I need to scan r two times, then it repeat please enter the argument twice, and it execute the second argument of r.

Comment: You run your program twice with the `fork`, so… what do you expect?

Comment: what do you mean? can you tell me please?

Comment: Sorry, sloppy wording. I oversaw Joachim Pileborg's answer, who already tells you what to do. Maybe the example [here](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=pipe&apropos=0&sektion=2&manpath=Debian+7.0+wheezy&format=html&locale=en) is helpful for you, they do something similar. And I'm not sure, what exactly you're trying to do. E.g. what is that `for` loop for? You break out of it unconditionally.

Answer (score 1):

Add break instruction after each case in switch.

Comment: Not needed in this case. `execl` will entirely replace the current process image.

Comment: Execl... functions return if error occurred, so breaks are needed. I agree that adding them won't solve the initial problem though.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that the child process starts executing the code directly after the `fork` call, that means that both the parent and child processes will call `scanf`. You need to check if you are in the child or parent process *directly* after the `fork` call.

You also need to have a `break` statement between the cases in the `switch` statement, or else when you do the first case the it will continue and to the second as well.

There is also the problem that the child processes never exit, but continue the endless loop. Once the child process is done it should `exit`.

You are also creating lots of "defunct" processes, in that you never [`wait`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wait.html) for your child processes. You need to call the `wait` function (or one of its related functions like `waitpid`) to "reap" the child. Otherwise the process will still be existing even even if it's in a state where it's paused.

Comment: How can I check if I am in child or parent process?

Comment: I still have the same problem.